# Limit Diverging in Absolute Value

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

As $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = C$ implies that $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} |f(z)| = |C|$, am I right to say that if the limit diverges in absolute value, then the limit of the original function must also diverge?

Comment: Sorry, I have removed that assumption.

Comment: You are correct; that is essentially the contrapositive of the original claim. Note that it holds for any continuous function in place of modulus (absolute value).